Elevation beamforming
For a uniform planar array with MN elements, the steering vector can be given as
$$a(\theta,\phi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{MN}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
\vdots\\
e^{j\pi\sin\phi[(m-1)\cos\theta+(n-1)\sin\theta]}\\
\vdots\\
e^{j\pi\sin\phi[(M-1)\cos\theta+(N-1)\sin\theta]}
\end{pmatrix}^{\text{T}}.$$
If I want to perform elevation beamforming such that the planar array can be seen as a uniform linear array, the elevation beamforming vector at elevation anlge $\phi_1$ should be
$$w_{mn}=e^{-j\pi\sin\phi_1(m-1)\cos\theta},$$
so the resulting equivalent ULA can be written as
$$
\tilde{a}(\theta)=[1,...,e^{j\pi\sin\phi(n-1)\sin\theta},...,e^{j\pi\sin\phi(N-1)\sin\theta}].
$$
Am I right?

not sure I understand your notation. What are the small $m$ and $n$ in your first equation?

@MarcusMüller M is the number of antenna elements in the x-axis, and N is the number of antenna elements in the y-axis

no, not the capital $N$ and $M$, but the small $m$ and $n$

I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings of the difference between a planar and linear array. If you take the elevation slice of a planar array (at broadside) over angles and compare it to a linear array of the same number of elements, spacing, and frequency, they are close to the same. What resources are you currently reading?

@MarcusMüller m refers to the m-th antenna element in the x-axis, and n refers to the n-th antenna element in the y-axis

@Envidia I am enquirying about the mathematical expression for the digital downtilt of a BS with a planar array.

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding between planar and linear arrays. If you have a uniform linear array (ULA), it will of course have a three-dimensional pattern. You fix your coordinates so that you're only looking over a set of angles to see a "slice" of the pattern, an example being what you have in your other question. Below is the array pattern of a 16-element ULA with an element spacing of $d = 0.5\lambda$ over the broadside angles:

The same is true for a uniform rectangular array (URA), except in this case you usually want to see over both azimuth and elevation. Below is the array pattern of a 16x16 element URA with an element spacing of $d = 0.5\lambda$:

If I then take the slice of URA where $az = 0$ over all elevation and compare it to the ULA, it's the same pattern response when normalizing to unity:

The major difference here is that the URA will have a higher peak directivity because of the additional elements, but the normalized shape of the pattern is the same, which is expected. Note there hasn't been any additional steering/beamforming of any sort, we simply used the array pattern equations found in literature for a ULA and URA and took a slice of the URA and compared it to another slice of the ULA.

Nice plots Envidia! I think you intended to mean "higher peak gain" in your final paragraph, as the directivity would be unchanged, right?

@DanBoschen I actually avoided using gain as the metric. The planar array indeed has a higher peak directivity than the linear array. The plots are normalized to show that the pattern shape between the two is the same.

Ah got it, I think -  because for the directivity computation it's normalized to the overall pattern not just the pattern shown as I was incorrectly thinking --- is that it?  (Actually I see now with regards to his other question for the linear only case how the directivity would be higher given that pattern simply revolves around the axis -- thanks for the clarification -- it's tough for me to think in 3D)

@DanBoschen The computation itself isn't normalized, but I did normalize the plots using each of their peak directivity to show that the shape of the pattern is the same. Did that answer the question?

" The planar array indeed has a higher peak directivity than the linear array." answered my question. I see how now.

We need to be clear on the coordinates and conventions. I typically use the physics convention for spherical coordinates as follows which is consistent with HFSS and other emag solvers:
(graphic copied from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

To answer the question and for further clarity, I'll show the formula for the complete 3D antenna pattern (Array Factor) for a planar array placed on the xy plane and then from that we can ask what occurs if we were to generate a pattern along the y-z plane (which would be equivalent to a linear array along y for the N elements along the y-axis), or a pattern along the x-z plane (which would be equivalent to a linear array along x for the M elements along the x-axis).
Given that assumption, the Array Factor (which is the resulting antenna pattern assuming all elements are omni-directional) is given as:
$$AF = \bar{w}^T\bar{v}(k) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}w_i e^{-jkr_i}$$
Where:
$\bar{w}$ is the vector of weights for a given target direction in 3D space
$\bar{v}(\bar{k})$ is the Steering Vector as established by the location of the elements in 3D space for a given wave vector $\bar{k}$.
$\bar{k}= (k_x, k_y, k_z)$ is the wave vector established by the incident wave (or transmitted wave) which has a magnitude of $2\pi/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the frequency used.
$r_i$ is the (x,y,z) position for antenna element $i$.
Because of the choice of coordinates describing $(r,\theta, \phi$ in 3D space specifically (which is why we need to be clear and include a diagram as I posted above), we have:
$x=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$
$u=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$
$z=r\cos(\theta)$
Resulting in:
$\bar{k} = (k_x, k_y, k_z) = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(\sin(\theta)cos(\phi), \sin(\theta)sin(\phi), cos(\theta))$
That said, if we wish to get the pattern along the x-z plane controlled by the M elements along the x-axis, we would set $\phi=0$ and vary $\theta$ resulting in the following steering vector:
$$\bar{v}(\bar{k}) = [e^{-j\bar{k} r_0}, e^{-j\bar{k} r_1}, \ldots e^{-j\bar{k} r_{M-1}}]$$
for $M$ elements placed along the y-axis
with $\bar{k} = [k_0, k_1, \ldots k_{M-1}]$ given as:
$\cos(\phi) = \cos(0) =1$ 
$\sin(\phi) = \sin(0) =0$ 
$$\bar{k} = (k_x, k_y, k_z) = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(\sin(\theta), 0, cos(\theta))$$
If the elements given by positions $r$ are all located on the xy plane, then $r_z=0$ and $k_z$ would not be a factor resulting in the pattern along the x-z plane only being dependent on $\sin(\theta)$ and the position $r$ along the $x$ axis.
Similarly, if we wish to get the pattern along the y-z plane controlled by the N elements along the y-axis, we would set $\phi=\pi/2$ radians (90 degrees) and vary $\theta$ resulting in the following steering vector:
$$\bar{v}(\bar{k}) = [e^{-j\bar{k} r_0}, e^{-j\bar{k} r_1}, \ldots e^{-j\bar{k} r_{N-1}}]$$
for the $N$ elements placed along the x-axis.
with $\bar{k} = [k_0, k_1, \ldots k_{N-1}]$ given as:
$\cos(\phi) = \cos(\pi/2) =0$ 
$\sin(\phi) = \sin(\pi/2) =1$ 
$$\bar{k} = (k_x, k_y, k_z) = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(0, \sin(\theta), cos(\theta))$$
If the elements given by positions $r$ are all located on the xy plane, then $r_z=0$ and $k_z$ would not be a factor resulting in the pattern along the y-z plane only being dependent on $\sin(\theta)$ and the position of the elements $r$ along the $y$ axis.
